# Как реализовать такой timepicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

Как релизовать подобный timepicker. Или вообще как сделать свой собственный. Встроенный в andoid studio дефолтный меня не устраивает (или может можно полностью стилизовать его). Материала никакого не нашел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На гитхабе полно библиотек, выбирайте что-нибудь: https://github.com/search?q=android+timepicker&type=

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)